# ¿Submit en php que redirija a paginas distintas?

Tags: php, html, submit

Buenos dias, Tengo un problema. Estoy empezando en php y lo que pasa es que dividi mi codigo en varios archivos para no tener todo revuelto en un solo archivo. Estoy haciendo una entrada tipo login sin embargo tengo dos opciones; una permite el login del administrador y otra del usuario asi que quiero reutilizar el codigo que tengo aparte en un archivo llamado login:

```
<body>

<?php require 'vali.php' ?>
<?php require 'header.php' ?>                    <!--"require" pide la informacion de la direccion especificada-->

  <h1>LOGIN</h1>

  <form action="menu.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="nick" placeholder="Nick" onkeypress= "return sololetras(event)" onpaste= "return false">
    <input type="text" name="contrasena" placeholder="Contraseña">
    <input type="submit" value="Entrar">
  </form>
```

el problema ahora es que este form unicamente redirige a "menu.php" que es el menu principal del administrador. Lo que quiero es que si en el index selecciona login como usuario, envie al menu del usuario y si se selecciona como administrador pues que envie al menu administrador...
Estaba pensando hacerlo con un if o algo asi, pero no se, o quizas lo que estoy pidiendo sea simplemente ridiculo, no se; ayuda por favor.

El codigo donde selecciono si logear como admin o como usuario es:

```
<body>

  <h1>SISTEMA TEST</h1>

  <form class="" action="controlador/login.php" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Administrador">
  </form>

  <form action="controlador/login.php" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Usuario">
  </form>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Martin, vas por buen camino.

Lo correcto en este tipo de escenarios donde tenes dos tipos de roles (usuario, admin) es tener un solo tipo de login. Y cuando validas las credenciales del usuario o admin (que al final del dia son un registro mas en la misma tabla) validas el rol que tenga.

En base al rol decidis si lo redirigis a una pantalla o a la otra.

No te olvides de chequear todo el tiempo el rol del usuario!! Con eso vas a evitar que un usuario "normal" tenga acceso a las pantallas de un usuario "administrador".

Espero haberte ayudado! Abrazo

Comment: Revisar [answer].